# Does Methyl Iodide (CH3I) react with water (H2O) and if it does what would be its byproducts?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Does Methyl Iodide ($\ce{CH3I}$) react with water ($\ce{H2O}$) and if it does what would be its byproducts?

A project I am designing requires a reaction with methyl iodide and a polar compound, so I was wondering if methyl iodide reacts with water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Methyl iodide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_iodide) is hydrolyzed by water in an $\ce{S_{N}2}$ reaction ($\ce{S_{N}1}$ is disfavored by the instability of the primary methyl cation), which yields methanol and hydroiodic acid as products.

$$\ce{CH3I + H2O <=> CH3OH2^+ + I-}$$
$$\ce{CH3OH2^+ + H2O <=> H3O+ + CH3OH}$$

A possible side reaction is the formation of iodine and methane by the redox reaction

$$\ce{CH3I + H3O+ + I- <=> CH4 + I2 + H2O}$$

However, this reaction becomes only important when a large concentration of methanol pushes the hydrolysis equilibrium to the educt side. It is negligible in pure aqueous solution ([reference](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01275a507)).

Answer (score 0):

In common condition, it reacts very slowly and will generate HI and CH3OH. It's soluble. If you don't heat in reaction, I think it's OK. It's very very toxic so take care..